# Добавить концентрические линии вокруг прямоугольника в SVG

Tags: html, svg, svg-filter

Я пытаюсь создать прямоугольник с тремя `borders` вокруг, используя фильтры. Результат должен выглядеть так:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

но мой результат выглядит так:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Мой код:

```html
<svg width=1000 height=1000 >
    <rect width=300 height=50 rx=25 x=100 y=100 filter="url(#filter)" fill="white"></rect>
    <filter id="filter">

      <feFlood flood-color="RGBA(173, 15, 91, 1.00)" result="fill1"></feFlood>
      <feMorphology in="SourceAlpha" operator="dilate" radius="8" result="radius1"></feMorphology>
      <feComposite in="fill1" in2="radius1" operator="in" result="compose1"></feComposite>
     
      <feFlood flood-color="RGBA(217, 145, 180, 1.00)" result="fill2"></feFlood>
      <feMorphology in="SourceAlpha" operator="dilate" radius="16" result="radius2"></feMorphology>
      <feComposite in="fill2" in2="radius2" operator="in" result="compose2"></feComposite>
      
           
      <feFlood flood-color="RGBA(247, 231, 239, 1.00)" result="fill3"></feFlood>
      <feMorphology in="SourceAlpha" operator="dilate" radius="24" result="radius3"></feMorphology>
      <feComposite in="fill3" in2="radius3" operator="in" result="compose3"></feComposite>
      
      <feMerge result="a452afbd-5e3f-4c25-abcf-3c77051dd340">
        <feMergeNode in="compose3"></feMergeNode>
        <feMergeNode in="compose2"></feMergeNode>

        <feMergeNode in="compose1"></feMergeNode>
        <feMergeNode in="SourceGraphic"></feMergeNode>

      </feMerge>
    </filter>
  </svg>
```

Приветствуется любая идея, как сделать это правильно, см. второй скриншот,  используя фильтры.

<sub>Свободный перевод вопроса [Add concentric lines around a rect in svg](https://stackoverflow.com/q/66384466/7394871) от участника  [@Andreas Köberle](https://stackoverflow.com/users/184883/andreas-k%c3%b6berle).</sub>

Comment: ассоциация:https://stackoverflow.com/q/66384466/7394871

Answer (score 1):

Вам просто нужно увеличить границы фильтра, чтобы они выходили достаточно далеко за пределы фильтруемого объекта.
Значения по умолчанию - дополнительные `y="-10%"` во всех направлениях, но этого недостаточно для вашего варианта использования.

Я выбрал `y="-70%"`

```html
<svg width=1000 height=1000 >
    <rect width=300 height=50 rx=25 x=100 y=100 filter="url(#filter)" fill="white"></rect>
    <filter id="filter" y="-70%" height="240%">

      <feFlood flood-color="RGBA(173, 15, 91, 1.00)" result="fill1"></feFlood>
      <feMorphology in="SourceAlpha" operator="dilate" radius="8" result="radius1"></feMorphology>
      <feComposite in="fill1" in2="radius1" operator="in" result="compose1"></feComposite>
     
      <feFlood flood-color="RGBA(217, 145, 180, 1.00)" result="fill2"></feFlood>
      <feMorphology in="SourceAlpha" operator="dilate" radius="16" result="radius2"></feMorphology>
      <feComposite in="fill2" in2="radius2" operator="in" result="compose2"></feComposite>
      
           
      <feFlood flood-color="RGBA(247, 231, 239, 1.00)" result="fill3"></feFlood>
      <feMorphology in="SourceAlpha" operator="dilate" radius="24" result="radius3"></feMorphology>
      <feComposite in="fill3" in2="radius3" operator="in" result="compose3"></feComposite>
      
      <feMerge result="a452afbd-5e3f-4c25-abcf-3c77051dd340">
        <feMergeNode in="compose3"></feMergeNode>
        <feMergeNode in="compose2"></feMergeNode>

        <feMergeNode in="compose1"></feMergeNode>
        <feMergeNode in="SourceGraphic"></feMergeNode>

      </feMerge>
    </filter>
  </svg>
```

<sub>Свободный перевод  [ответа](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66384585/7394871) от участника  [@Robert Longson](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1038015/robert-longson).</sub>

Answer (score 1):

Если вы хотите сохранить форму, вы не можете использовать `feMorphology`, потому что он использует квадратное ядро с равным весом. Вместо этого вам нужно использовать размытие и альфа-усиление (он же липкий (gooey) эффект). (Также нужно увеличить регион действия фильтра)

```html
<svg width="1000px" height="1000px" >
    <rect width=300 height=50 rx=25 x=100 y=100 filter="url(#filter)" fill="white"></rect>
    <filter id="filter" x="-50%" y="-100%" height="400%" width="200%" color-interpolation-filters="sRGB">

      <feFlood flood-color="RGBA(173, 15, 91, 1.00)" result="fill1"/>
      <feGaussianBlur stdDeviation="8" in="SourceGraphic"/>
      <feColorMatrix type="matrix" values="1 0 0 0 0  0 1 0 0 0  0 0 1 0 0  0 0 0 20 -2" result="radius1"/>
      <feComposite in="fill1" in2="radius1" operator="in" result="compose1"/>
     
      <feFlood flood-color="RGBA(217, 145, 180, 1.00)" result="fill2"/>
      <feGaussianBlur stdDeviation="8" in="compose1"  />
      <feColorMatrix type="matrix" values="1 0 0 0 0  0 1 0 0 0  0 0 1 0 0  0 0 0 20 -2" result="radius2"/>
      <feComposite in="fill2" in2="radius2" operator="in" result="compose2"/>
      
           
      <feFlood flood-color="RGBA(247, 231, 239, 1.00)" result="fill3"/>
      <feGaussianBlur stdDeviation="8" in="compose2"/>
      <feColorMatrix type="matrix" values="1 0 0 0 0  0 1 0 0 0  0 0 1 0 0  0 0 0 20 -2" result="radius3"/>
      <feComposite in="fill3" in2="radius3" operator="in" result="compose3"/>
      
      <feMerge result="a452afbd-5e3f-4c25-abcf-3c77051dd340">
        <feMergeNode in="compose3"></feMergeNode>
        <feMergeNode in="compose2"></feMergeNode>
        <feMergeNode in="compose1"></feMergeNode>
        <feMergeNode in="SourceGraphic"></feMergeNode>
      </feMerge>
    </filter>
  </svg>
```

<sub>Свободный перевод  [ответа](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66386712/7394871) от участника  [@Michael Mullany](https://stackoverflow.com/users/271353/michael-mullany).</sub>